# Is it possible to loop sound in the speaker?

Tags: audio

I'm rendering a scene and using speakers and I want one sound to loop the entire time. Is it possible?

Comment: there is no loop. you have to duplicate it over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up NLA editor:

[image]

Then duplicate sound strip as many times as you want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also render the sound separately and add it later in the video editor, where you can loop it. Just copy the sound strip along your rendered animation.